# On the relation between Laplace transform of a function and its derivative

Tags: laplace-transform

Suppose that $s>s_0$. Through integration by parts we can write $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st} f'(t)~\mathrm dt= \Big[ e^{-st} f(t)\Big]_0^\infty + s \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt. $$ Book ODE by Rabenstein says that if $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st} f'(t)~\mathrm dt$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt$ exist then $\lim_{\ t \to +\infty} (e^{-st} f(t)) =0 $.

My question is : What is the proof to the statement that if the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t)~\mathrm dt$ is well defined then must the limit $\lim_{r\to+\infty}g(r)=0$ ?

Comment: Don't forget $\mathrm dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through integration by parts we can actually write 
$$
\int_{0}^re^{-st} f'(t)~\mathrm dt= \Big[ e^{-st} f(t)\Big]_0^r + s \int_{0}^re^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\int_{0}^re^{-st} f'(t)~\mathrm dt-s \int_{0}^re^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt=e^{-sr} f(r)-f(0).
$$
The existence of the two improper integrals implies that one can take $r\to+\infty$ on the left and so also on the right. This shows that $\lim_{r\to+\infty}(e^{-sr} f(r))$ is well defined.

Moreover, the limit $$c=\lim_{r\to+\infty}(e^{-sr} f(r))$$ can only be zero since otherwise (and since the limit exists) the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt$ would not be well defined. Indeed, if $c\ne0$, then given $\delta>0$, there exists $T>0$ such that $|e^{-st} f(t)-c|<\delta$ for $t>T$ and so $$\int_T^re^{-st} f(t)~\mathrm dt>(c-\delta)(r-T)\to+\infty$$
when $r\to+\infty$, provided that $\delta<c$ and *assuming here for simplicity that all is real although we can simply consider real and imaginary parts*.

Comment: As I wrote in the "added", the problem is that why convergence of some integral from $0$ to $\infty$ implies that limit of its integrand is zero when approached to $\infty$? This should be in some real analysis text by I can't find (maybe because I don't know a name if its theorem has a name). In other words, what is the proof of your statement in the last paragraph of your answer?

Comment: You are assuming the existence of **two** integrals (right?), not of **one** integral, and so, unless you drastically change your original question (or taken from the book you mention), you now have your answer.

Comment: I edited. Thanks. :)

Comment: What are you asking now is false in general. It is really necessary to assume that the two integrals exist.

Comment: "It is really important to assume that the two integrals exist." why?

Comment: Because otherwise there is a counterexample: there are functions $g$ for which $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t)~\mathrm dt$ is well defined but for which the limit $\lim_{r\to+\infty}g(r)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think that I can't reach the answer is that I couldn't target my question properly; in a better way: all my question is could you please provide a proof for the last paragraph in your answer? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I will add some details to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry because I can't express my question. I was asking for a proof of all the statement in the last paragraph of your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. :)) [I evaluated for c<0 also, it also diverge]

Answer (score 0):

If you write down the integration by parts formula for the integral from $0$ to $R$, then your assumption implies that the term on the left and the second summand on the right have a limit as $R \to +\infty$, which implies that $\lim\limits_{t \to +\infty} e^{-st} f(t)$ exists. If this limit was not $0$, then the improper integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of this function would diverge.

Comment: Could you please help me to know why "If this limit was not $0$, then the improper integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of this function would diverge."? thanks